# Filter internal traffic in Analytics and variable IP

Tags: google-analytics

How to filter internal traffic in Google Analytics if I do not have a fix IP?

I have followed Google instructions and I only see the option of filtering introducing my IP
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823

But I have consulted my hosting provider and it says that I have a variable IP. To have a fix IP would be much complex and expensive.

Do I have any other way to exclude my own visits from Google Analytics?

Comment: Have you verified how often the IP changes? Variable does not mean that changes are necessarily frequent.

Comment: Does your site have a login?   Are you logged in as administrator?

Comment: How much control do you have over the server?  Can you modify the code running the site? Edit .htaccess files?

Comment: @Anaksunaman: My hosting provider says that they cannot predict how often it can change. The server is shared by differents domains.

Comment: @Stephen: Yes. I have a username and password and I use Cyberduck to upload the files

Comment: @Stephen: I have programmed the site myself. I do not use Wordpress, Druppal or any other CMS. I know .htaccess and I am familiar with Regex to make redirections there